# Как передать post данные без формы ввода

Tags: javascript, python, post, selenium, requests

Есть форма в котором 2 поля ввода: Имя, Фамилия. Но я увидел что в post запрос помимо ferstname, lastname отправляется еще пустой password выглядит это вот так:
Request from data:

```
firstname: "David"
lastname: "Davidka"
password: ""
```

Как мне добавить в password значения, если формы ввода для password нет?
Заранее говорю get`ом в моем случае нельзя пользоватся 
Пытался через firefox edit html вставить форму с name=password, и нажать на кнопку отправки, не получилось
Адрес сайта:
https://connect.vk.com/

Comment: вы в selenium нажимаете кнопку или, все же, пользуетесь requests и отправляете им?

Comment: Для нажатие кнопки я пользуеюсь selenium, requests я пытался отправить get'ом, но не получилось, и как мне сказали что не получится.

Comment: если вы можете в selenium заполнить firstname и lastname и нажать - больше ничего не нужно делать: скрипт, привязанный к кнопке, сам добавит пустой password...

Comment: Мне нужно именно чтобы password был не пустым.

Comment: дайте адрес страницы?

Comment: https://connect.vk.com/